# Retrieve nested objects from firestore to recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

How do we retrieve the nested objects from firestore and display them in recycler view?  From the database, I want to retrieve the nested objects of products into the recycler view so that all the products with their details are displayed there. Attaching the code of model class and adapter.

**MODEL CLASS**

```
public class ProductModelClass
{

    String Category, Details,Measure,Name;
    Number DiscountPrice, NumberofProducts, Price;

    public ProductModelClass()
    {

    }

    public ProductModelClass(String category, String details, String measure, String name, Number discountPrice, Number numberofProducts, Number price)
    {
        Category = category;
        Details = details;
        Measure = measure;
        Name = name;
        DiscountPrice = discountPrice;
        NumberofProducts = numberofProducts;
        Price = price;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        Category = category;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return Details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        Details = details;
    }

    public String getMeasure() {
        return Measure;
    }

    public void setMeasure(String measure) {
        Measure = measure;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Number getDiscountPrice() {
        return DiscountPrice;
    }

    public void setDiscountPrice(Number discountPrice) {
        DiscountPrice = discountPrice;
    }

    public Number getNumberofProducts() {
        return NumberofProducts;
    }

    public void setNumberofProducts(Number numberofProducts) {
        NumberofProducts = numberofProducts;
    }

    public Number getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Number price) {
        Price = price;
    }
    }
```

**ADAPTER**

```
 public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {
    
        private OnItemClickListener listener = null;
    
        ArrayList<ProductModelClass> data;
    
        public ProductListAdapter(ArrayList<ProductModelClass> data, OnItemClickListener listener) {
            this.data = data;
            this.listener = listener;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewTyp) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.products_item, null);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
            holder.productTitle.setText(data.get(position).getName());
            holder.productQty.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getNumberofProducts()));
            holder.productPrice.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getPrice()));
            holder.productOffer.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getDiscountPrice()));
            //binding onClickListener
            holder.bind(data.get(position),listener);
        }
    
    
        public interface OnItemClickListener
        {
            void onItemClick(ProductModelClass item);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return data.size();
        }
    
        
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            TextView productTitle, productQty, productPrice, productOffer;
            MaterialButton availability;
    
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                productTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
                productQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_sub);
                productPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
                productOffer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_offer_price);
                availability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.availability_prod);
            }
    
            public void bind(ProductModelClass productmodelclass, OnItemClickListener listener)
            {
                itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> listener.onItemClick(productmodelclass));
            }
    
        }
    }
```

[This is the structure of my database. I want to retrieve all the different products under tablets and mobiles in my recycler view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgq2e.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact objects you want to get.

Comment: Since `Tablets` and `Mobiles` are arrays of objects, then you should consider reading this article, [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).

Comment: @AlexMamo No its a map inside map..Nesting of multiple maps

Comment: In that case, you should iterate through the Map and get the corresponding objects, right?

Comment: Yes, basically I want to retrieve the product data inside Product1, Product2 etc into the recycler view. Here we need to give it the path till Product1....product --> Tablets --> Product1 --> The data to be retrieved. (All the above are maps)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact content of those maps.